# Access element in parent window which is dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i access a dynamically created element in a parent window from whithin an iframe. My way:

1. Click Button -> jQuery insert #element
2. Open iframe -> click on close botton -> close window and get text from textarea and NOW...

I want to put this text in #element which is located at the parent window.

Any ideas??

Ok sorry, i don't know why but now it works.

```
$(document).on("click", "#closefancy", function() {
    var value = CKEDITOR.instances['humboldt'].getData();
    $('#new_text', window.parent.document).val(value);
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I use to access the opening parent window is this:

```
if (window.dialogArguments) {
    opener = window.dialogArguments;
} else {
    if (window.opener)
        opener = window.opener;
}
```

So you could then use
    opener.document. to access the parent document